# Average as a constant approximation in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory

Let $I=[0,1]$. For $p\in[1,\infty]$ define $C_p$ as the best constant such that for all $f\in L^p(I)$
$$
\left\|f-\int_If\,\right\|_{L^p(I)}\leq C_p\inf_{c\in\mathbb{R}}\left\|f-c\,\right\|_{L^p(I)}.
$$
The following properties are fairly elementary:

- $1\leq C_p\leq 2$. The first inequality is trivial, the second follows by convexity: for any $c$
  $$
  \left\|f-\int_If\,\right\|_{L^p(I)}\leq \left\|f-c\,\right\|_{L^p(I)}+\left\|c-\int_If\,\right\|_{L^p(I)}\leq 2\left\|f-c\,\right\|_{L^p(I)}.
  $$
- $C_2=1$. This is a standard argument: to minimize $\left\|f-c\,\right\|_{L^2(I)}^2$ we differentiate with respect to $c$:
  $$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial c}\left\|f-c\,\right\|_{L^2(I)}^2=2c-2\int_I f,
  $$
  so the average is the minimizer.
- $C_\infty=2$. No better constant exists for the sequence $f_n=n\mathbf{1}_{[0,1/n]}$. Indeed, $\|f_n-1\|_{L^\infty(I)}=n-1$ and the optimal choice is $\|f_n-n/2\|_{L^\infty(I)}=n/2$.
- $C_1=2$. For the same sequence $f_n=n\mathbf{1}_{[0,1/n]}$, one has $\|f_n-1\|_{L^1(I)}=2(n-1)/n$ and the optimal choice is $\|f_n-0\|_{L^1(I)}=1$.

What can be said about $p\neq 1,2,\infty$? The topic of best constant (or more generally, polynomial) approximation is very classical but I could not find results on this particular question.

Based on the above, I computed numerically the suggested constant by taking $f_{100}$, which gives the corresponding approximate lower bounds

- $C_3\geq 1.0553$
- $C_4\geq  1.1465$
- $C_5\geq 1.2340$
- $C_6\geq  1.3096$
- $C_{10}\geq 1.5114$
- $C_{15}\geq   1.6425$
- $C_{25}\geq   1.7645$

Comment: A simple remark you probably know already: by duality, $C_p= C_q$ when $1/p + 1/q = 1$.

Comment: @WillieWong Hi. I'm stupid. Would you mind spelling out the duality argument?

Comment: As [noted below](https://mathoverflow.net/a/431865/3948), the $C_p$ you are looking for is the best constant for the projection operator $f \mapsto f - \int_I f$ mapping a function to its mean-zero part treated as a mapping $L^p\to L^p$. This sounds like an even more natural problem than the one you phrased, and so likely there is existing literature.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for the many nice comments and observations! I'll see if searching with this reformulation yields something

Answer (score 5):

### Upper bounds

This is not a full answer. But provides some ideas.

#### Duality

First, I'd like to spell out the duality argument and show that if $\frac1p + \frac1q = 1$, then $C_p = C_q$.

For this we will need the well-known dual characterization of $L^p$ norms:
$$ \|f \|_p = \sup_{g: \|g\|_q = 1} \int fg $$
Now, on the left we want to estimate $\| f- \int f\|_p$, so we compute, for an arbitrary $g\in L^q$ with unit norm the quantity $\int (f - \int f)g$. Observe that since $f-\int f$ has zero mean, its integrals against constants vanish. So we have
$$ \int (f-\int f)g = \int (f-\int f)(g - \int g) $$
Now modifying $f$ using the same reason, we find
$$ = \int (f-c)(g-\int g) \leq \|f-c\|_p \|g - \int g\|_q $$
where we applied, for the inequality, Holder's inequality.

To conclude, we have that for any $f\in L^p$ and $g\in L^q$ that
$$ \int (f-\int f)g \leq \|f - c\|_p \|g - \int g\|_q \leq \|f - c\|_p \cdot C_q \|g - c'\|_q $$
for any $c'\in \mathbb{R}$.
This in particular applies to $c' = 0$.

Now optimizing over all $g$ with $\|g\|_q = 1$ you find
$$ \|f - \int f\|_p \leq C_q \|f - c\|_p $$
for every $f\in L^p$ and every $c\in \mathbb{R}$. This shows that $C_p \leq C_q$.

But the argument is symmetric in $p$ and $q$, thus we conclude that $C_p = C_q$.

#### Interpolation bounds

First note that the question can be rephrased as looking for the operator norm of the linear operator $T: f \mapsto f - \int f$, since given $g = T(f)$, then $T^{-1}(g) = \{ f + c: c\in \mathbb{R}\}$. So the problem of finding the operator norm of $T$ can be written as finding

$$ \sup_{f\in L^p\setminus \{0\}} \frac{\|Tf\|_p}{\|f\|_p} = 
\sup_{g\in L^p\setminus \{0\}, \int g = 0} \sup_{f \in T^{-1}(g)} \frac{\|g\|_p}{\|f\|_p} = \sup_{g\in L^p\setminus \{0\}, \int g = 0} \frac{\|g\|_p}{\inf_{c} \|g+c\|_p}$$

The fact that $C_p$ can be found explicitly for $p = 1, 2, \infty$ means that you can apply Riesz-Thorin-Stein interpolation.

For $p > 2$, we can write it as
$$ \frac1p = \frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{1-\theta}{\infty}$$
(or more simply, $\theta = 2/p$). Complex interpolation tells us that our operator having operator norm $C_2 = 1$ and $C_\infty = 2$ must have operator norm
$$ C_p \leq C_2^\theta C_\infty^{1-\theta} = 2^{1-\theta} = 2^{1-2/p}$$
In particular, $C_p < 2$ for all $p \neq 1,\infty$.

For comparison, here are the numerical values of the function above:

| $p$ | $2^{1-2/p}$ |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1.26 |
| 4 | 1.414 |
| 5 | 1.516 |
| 6 | 1.587 |
| 8 | 1.682 |
| 10 | 1.741 |
| 15 | 1.823 |
| 20 | 1.866 |
| 25 | 1.892 |
| 50 | 1.945 |

So you see that the numerical lower bounds are compatible with the theoretical upper bounds, but there is a gap.

Comment: "Another" being, presumably, a reference to your [earlier answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/431832).

Answer (score 4):

### Lower Bounds

Let $f_\sigma$ be the function that equals $1/\sigma$ on $[0,\sigma]$ and $0$ otherwise (generalizing your $f_n$), you can actually compute by hand that $\inf \|f_\sigma - c\|_{p}$ is achieved with
$$ c = \frac{1}{\sigma + \sigma (1/\sigma - 1)^{1/(p-1)}} $$
This yields the ratio (and lower bound for $C_p$)
$$ \frac{\|f_\sigma - \int f_\sigma\|_p}{\|f_\sigma - c\|_p} = \left( \sigma^{p-1} + (1-\sigma)^{p-1}\right)^{1/p}\left( \sigma^{1/(p-1)} + (1-\sigma^{1/(p-1)}\right)^{1-1/p} $$
from which you see that your numerical values based on $f_{100}$ are underestimates (rather significantly so when $p\in (2,10]$).

Numerically optimizing the above expression gives you slightly more refined bounds

| $p$ | lower bound for $C_p$ |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1.095 |
| 4 | 1.212 |
| 5 | 1.302 |
| 6 | 1.374 |
| 8 | 1.478 |
| 10 | 1.55 |
| 15 | 1.662 |
| 20 | 1.727 |
| 25 | 1.769 |
| 50 | 1.867 |

---

**Additional Numerical Results**

The computations above maximized a quotient for $f$ that can be expressed as a step function with at most two distinct output values.
For what it is worth, I wrote up a numerical optimization routine that computed the lower bound for $C_p$ when $f$ can be expressed as a step function with no more than *three* distinct output values.

Interestingly the optimal values found for $C_p$ are **identical** to those listed in the table above, and the optimal function found are those that only has two distinct output values (so can be identified as one of the $f_\sigma$ above). So there's a chance that the values above are sharp.

For those interested: the code is below (in `julia` using `JuMP`)
The function is normalized to have one (the largest in absolute value) of the three output values to be $-1$ (since the problem is scale invariant). The variables `w1`, `w2`, `w3` are the widths of the three segments, and `h1`, `h2` are the other two heights of the step function. The variable `c` is the constant that is to be subtracted. Execute the `findCp` function with the value of `p` you want. The last variable in the output is the value of $C_p$ found.

I tried with a few different initial seed function values, and they all seem to converge to the same answer.

`````
using JuMP, Ipopt

function findCp(p)
        model = Model(Ipopt.Optimizer)
        set_silent(model)
        @variable(model, -1<= h1<=1, start = 0.0)
        @variable(model, -1<= h2<= 1, start = 1/2)
        @variable(model, 0<= w1 <= 1, start = 1/4)
        @variable(model, 0<= w2 <= 1, start = 1/2)
        @variable(model, 0<= w3 <= 1, start = 1/4)
        @variable(model, c)
        @constraint(model,  w1+w2+w3 == 1)
        @constraint(model, h1*w1 + h2*w2 - w3 == 0)

        @NLobjective(model, Max, (abs(h1)^p*w1 + abs(h2)^p*w2 + w3) / (abs(h1-c)^p*w1 + abs(h2-c)^p*w2 + abs(1+c)^p*w3) )

        optimize!(model)
        return value(h1), value(h2), value(w1), value(w2), value(w3), value(c), objective_value(model)^(1/p)
end

findCp(3)
````
`````

Comment: Longer compared, presumably, to the short remark in your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431821/average-as-a-constant-approximation-in-lp#comment1111498_431821).

Comment: Well, since it got longer after the last edit: I guess it is also longer than my other answer.

Comment: Ha, [yes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431821/average-as-a-constant-approximation-in-lp/431832#comment1111602_431832)!  I wasn't fussing about the length; just sometimes it can get confusing when answers refer to earlier answers, or above answers, or whatever, when the answers might get jumbled in later sorting, so I like to leave explicit links for anyone future archæologists.

Comment: Your efforts are much appreciated! (I know I've come across multi-answer questions where your comments helped me navigate.)

Comment: @WillieWong Do you have a proof that $C_p < 2$ for *some* $p \not = 2$? E.g. $p=4$?

Comment: @mathworker21 It follows from interpolation. I provide details in [my other answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/431865/3948)

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you very much for your responses and posts.

Comment: @mathworker21 The answer is $\sup_{x,y>0,x+y=1}[(x^{p-1}+y^{p-1})^{1/p}(x^{q-1}+y^{q-1})^{1/q}]$ where $\frac 1p+\frac 1q=1$. It is unclear to me if this quantity has any nicer representation.

Comment: @WillieWong This turns out to not be that bad. Fedja's proof is as follows. One can assume wlog that $\int f = 0$ and $c=1$. Then one just wants the smallest $C_p > 0$ so that $C_p|t-1|^p-|t|^p+\lambda t \ge 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, from which the result follows by integrating (setting $t=f$). The optimal $C_p$ is such that the line touching the graph of $C_p|t-1|^p-|t|^p$ at two points passes through the origin, and matches what your answer gives.